# How can I check whether the SnapStart optimisations for my Quarkus Lambda are actually working?

Tags: java, aws-lambda, quarkus

so I have a Quarkus application on Java17 running as a Lambda function.
I'm using the "io.quarkus:quarkus-amazon-lambda" extension for this.

Following the blog post about SnapStart(https://quarkus.io/guides/amazon-snapstart),
I now have a long list of class names in `scr/main/resources/META-INF/quarkus-preload-classes.txt`.

However the runtime of the Lambda (after RESTORE_START, RESTORE_END demonstrating that the Snapshot was used) still is extremely long (5+ seconds for accepting a request, parsing it and storing it in a DynamoDB).

I would like to ensure that the classes are actually preloaded, as I'm not seeing any logs about this preloading during Snapshot creation (even with DEBUG log level), do you know what settings I maybe have to update? Or where to look exactly?

Thanks a lot!

```
...
sun.util.logging.PlatformLogger
sun.util.logging.PlatformLogger$Bridge
sun.util.logging.PlatformLogger$ConfigurableBridge
sun.util.logging.PlatformLogger$ConfigurableBridge$LoggerConfiguration
sun.util.logging.PlatformLogger$Level
sun.util.logging.internal.LoggingProviderImpl
sun.util.logging.internal.LoggingProviderImpl$JULWrapper
sun.util.logging.internal.LoggingProviderImpl$LogManagerAccess
sun.util.resources.Bundles
sun.util.resources.Bundles$1
...
```

Comment: Do you use client priming for dynamodb? Dynamo is really heavy to instantiate. I would recommend snapshotting it.

Comment: Yes, I'm instantiating it inside a method that's observing the StartupEvent like so:
`
 void startup(@Observes StartupEvent event,
                 DynamoDbClient dynamoDbClient) {
        dynamoDbClient.toString();
`

But the question remains how I can check that the classes are actually preloaded, as I don't see any output of this in the DEBUG logs

Comment: Are you sure you are invoking a SnapStart enabled version of the Lambda function?

Comment: Hi, yes, we can see in the logs that a lambda version is called (not $LATEST) and that there is a RESTORE phase.